# How to construct a 3D background by tilting CCSprite around X and/or Y axes using cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm trying to create a 3D background with a lava texture. It needs to be tilted around the x axis by 90 degrees to give an illusion of floor. It needs to be able to scroll in any direction infinitely as well.

There is no rotateX or rotateY in CCSprite, and I tried to use CCCamera to achieve a similar effect, but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted either. I also tried CCOrbitCamera, this made the floor rotate constantly which is not desirable.

I also considered writing a subclass of CCSprite, calling CCSprite3D, but don't know what functions to override.

How do I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at CameraOrbitTest in [cocosnodeTest](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop/tests/cocosnodeTest.m).